# NotesDocument.getItemValue exception when submit

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I defined "dbProfileDoc" as global variable for database profile in ssjs library.  I have managed to get database profile and dbProfileDoc.getItemValue(fieldname) is working at AfterPageLoad event.  However, I got exception thrown out when trying to dbProfileDoc.getItemValue(fieldname) at Submit button to submit my xpages.  The dbProfileDoc is still alive but could not access any field value on submit.  Is anyone please tell me what is happening?

Comment: Then I tried to get database profile again:  dbProfileDoc = database.getProfileDocument("DatabaseProfile", "DatabaseProfile");  It worked!!!  It come to my conclusion that we could not store NotesDocument object to ssjc global variable.  The question is that how come dProfielDoc object is not equal to null when tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes objects can't be stored in a variable for so long because they are not serializable.
You should store the values from Notes objects you need in variables and recycle the Notes objects right after it.

As an alternative, you can define your profile document as an additional data source for your XPage. Then you don't have to reread it every time you need it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  That will work but not the solution that I am looking for.  I am thinking to store db profile document in applicationScope variable with a test on it.  If null, then get it again.  Do you think that this is the best practice?  if (applicationScope.dbProfileDoc == null) {
   dbProfileDoc = database.getProfileDocument("myDataseProfile", "myDatabaseProfile");
  }

Comment: I think it is not best practice because you don't recycle the Notes document but create often new ones. I am also not sure if the applicationScope will be null. It might be not null but the reference to the Notes Document is not valid anymore. Why don't you put the values from Profile document into applicationScope variables?

Comment: Thanks! After I created new one, I will put to applicationScope and recycle the NotesDocument.  The main reason is that I can use applicationScope variable anywhere in xpages and it has many profile fields.  However, you are right, the reference to the NotesDocument is invalid even though it return true with a test to null but could not access it any more. I saw it return string 'null' but not object null.  very interesting.  What is the best way to test the Notes object in ssjs?

Comment: this is working for me: if ((applicationScope.dbProfileDoc == null) || (!applicationScope.dbProfileDoc.isValid())) {
   applicationScope.dbProfileDoc = database.getProfileDocument("myDatabaseProfile", "myDatabaseProfile");  I found that NoetsDocument become invalid when submitting the xpages.
  }
 },

Comment: Yes, NotesDocument becomes invalid when submitting the XPages. Why? Before you see the page on client it gets calculated and rendered. During that time your applicationScope with linked NotesDocument is created and you can use it. After the rendered page is sent to client server writes all data like your applicationScope to a save place and keeps it there until client sends submit. Server restores then all data back to memory objects and goes on with work for next calculating and rendering page. The only bad thing is that NotesDocument wasn't stored and cannot get restored (not serializable).

Comment: Thank you very much in explaining so professionally.  I really appreciated.  Thanks much.

Comment: I am glad you appreciated it and hope I could help you a bit :). I just saw that you've never voted up or accepted answers for your questions. The way how it works at StackOverflow is following: if an answer to your question is helpful then vote up by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer. If you are finally satisfied with answers and want to "close" your question then accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. You can still do it with your older questions. :)

Comment: Thanks for instruction.  Done that.